# Is there some special encoding required when sending ASCII commands over Serial (USB-RS232) port in Python3.8?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, serial-port

Firstly, I have also researched an seen that this question is answered alot of places, but the answers don't work for me.

I am trying to send ASCII command over serial port to a PCBA and then attempting to receive the response.

HW setup:

1. Computer
2. USB-RS232 Cable
3. PCBA

SW:
Python 3.8

I have sent commands over RS232 terminals (realterm) and they work perfectly (LED turns on) but can't implement the same with python. The command in question is "led_r_on".
And yes, I get "COM5 is open" prompt, meaning COM5 is alive.

Thanks for helps!

code as follows:
import serial
import time

```
from time import sleep
from serial import Serial

port = 'COM5'
baud = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=2)
if ser.isOpen():
  print(ser.name + ' is open...')

sleep(1)

ser.write(b'led_r_on')
print(ser.readline(1000))
```

Comment: Isn't the carriage return code missing at the end of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't give any information on the pcba you are using. I will just assume, that you are missing some kind of end delimiter in your bytesequence. Now there are many ways of ending a transmission over serial. The most frequent ones I ran across are these two:`b'led_r_on\r\n'` or just `b'led_r_on\n'`. Try changing your bytes in the `ser.write()` function to this. If that does not work you might need to use this: `b'led_r_on\x04'` this will send the EOT (End of Transmission) ASCII character. But I don't think this will be needed.

Comment: b'led_r_on\r\n' works!!
Thanks so much - so much head scratching.